# Keep file in git but remove locally

Tags: git

I'd like to remove a file locally while keeping it in future commits for git. `.gitignore` can't do this, as it only ignores changes (not deletions).

An example would (generally) be as follows:

- add & commit file
- ???
- remove file, keeping in git

**NB: This is not** `git rm --cached`**. What I want is the "opposite" of this.**

Comment: Maybe a selective checkout (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079)?

Comment: @david25272 I'm the maintainer of the repo. I just have an install file that I don't need, but still has to be in the repo. Hopefully that clears things up. (I'm not looking to clone anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `rm` (not `git rm`) should be enough.

But then, instruct the index that the file was not(!) deleted, with [`git update-index --assume-unchanged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#git-update-index---no-assume-unchanged):

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- a/file
```